# Custom classes on CLNDR.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to have some days beeing marked with classes other than "events" (eg.: "holiday"), so I could change its background, for example.

From CLNDR.js's site (http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/):

> CLNDR takes your template and injects some data into it. The data contains everything you need to create a calendar. Here's what you get:

```
daysOfTheWeek: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
numberOfRows: 5,
days: [
  {
    day: '1',
    classes: 'day today event',
    id: 'calendar-day-2013-09-01',
    events: [ ],
    date: moment('2013-09-01')
  }
]
month: 'September',
year: '2013',
eventsThisMonth: [ ],
extras: { }
```

I've tryed to add holidays into this "days" array:

```
  {
    day: '25',
    classes: '**holiday** day today event',
    id: 'calendar-day-2013-12-25',
    events: [ ],
    date: moment('2013-12-25')
  }
```

But no success

My code:

```
$('#clndr').clndr({
  template: $('#template').html(),
  clickEvents: {...},
  startWithMonth: ...,
  daysOfTheWeek: [...],
  days: [
    { 
      day: '25',
      classes: 'holiday calendar-day-2014-12-25',
      events: [],
      date: moment('2014-12-25')
     }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should define events of type holiday and in your template add a class when a day has a holiday event. Here the clndr.js developer has explained how to do it:

https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR/issues/6